# Concatenate GDB convenience variables

Tags: gdb

I'd like to do something like this, but can't figure out the right GDB commands.

Let's say I start debugging a process, and there is a file I'd like to pass as a parameter to that process.  I want to construct the name of the file at runtime with a gdb command script that would look something like this:

```
set $var1 = "path"
set $var2 = "to"
set $var3 = "file"
set $var4 = $var1+"/"+$var2+"/"+$var3
file /process/to/debug
run params $var4
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no really good built-in way to do this :-(

You might think, as I did, that the `eval` command could be used.  However, for the specific case of string substitutions, `eval` requires the inferior (FWIW this seems like a gdb bug to me).

That is, this works:

```
(gdb) set $v1 = 7
(gdb) eval "set $v2 = \"%d\"", $v1
(gdb) p $v2
$1 = "7"
```

But this does not:

```
(gdb) set $v3 = "hi"
(gdb) eval "set $v4 = \"%s\"", $v3
evaluation of this expression requires the target program to be active
```

There are still two routes you can use.

The traditional one is to use `set logging` in combination with `output` (`printf` won't work - it fails just as the above does) and perhaps `shell sed` or the like, to turn the strings into some gdb commands in a file.  Then `source` that file.

Another way is to write some Python code to do this.  You could either write a convenience function that concatenates strings, or you could write a new command that does whatever you happen to want.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah.  Scripting in gdb is not the best.  I should probably just cut my losses and go for python.

Answer (score 1):

This gdb Python user-defined convenience function implements a `$concat` function you use on arbitrary rvalues for this purpose.

```py
class Concat(gdb.Function):
    """$concat(arg, [arg, [arg, [...]]]): Concatenate strings"""

    def __init__(self):
        super(Concat, self).__init__("concat")

    def _unwrap_string(self, v):
        try:
            return v.string()
        except gdb.error:
            return str(v)
    
    def invoke(self, *args):
        return ''.join([ self._unwrap_string(x) for x in args])

Concat()
```

```
(gdb) source concat.py
(gdb) help function concat
$concat(arg, [arg, [arg, [...]]]): Concatenate strings
(gdb) p $concat(1,2,"foo",3,"bar")
$10 = "12foo3bar"
(gdb) p $concat( (char*)0 )
$14 = "0x0"
(gdb) $concat(argv[0])
$20 = "test_program"
(gdb) detach
...
(gdb) p $concat("works", " ", "when", " ", "detached")
$23 = "works when detached"
```

This implementation might do odd things if you aren't specific about input types and works best on actual strings.